# What does "375848K->125488K(4355072K)" mean in Java GC log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My Java GC log:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 267611K->5387K(255488K)] 386801K->125992K(4367872K), 0.0187757 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 255243K->4819K(242688K)] 375848K->125488K(4355072K), 0.0157165 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2015-10-16 16:30:53.623  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5194569f: startup date [Fri Oct 16 13:57:40 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-16 16:30:53.628  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-4] c.e.c.s.c.l.EnniuWeightedLoadBalancer    : Shutting down the Executor Pool for DynamicServerListLoadBalancer
2015-10-16 16:30:53.629  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@63510626: startup date [Fri Oct 16 13:57:44 CST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5194569f
2015-10-16 16:30:53.635  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-2] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2015-10-16 16:30:53.648  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2015-10-16 16:30:53.649  INFO 26072 ---      [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 242688K, used 100212K [0x0000000742800000, 0x000000075bf80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 237568K, 40% used [0x0000000742800000,0x0000000748528590,0x0000000751000000)
  from space 5120K, 94% used [0x000000075ba80000,0x000000075bf34d70,0x000000075bf80000)
  to   space 20992K, 0% used [0x0000000759680000,0x0000000759680000,0x000000075ab00000)
 ParOldGen       total 4112384K, used 120668K [0x0000000647800000, 0x0000000742800000, 0x0000000742800000)
  object space 4112384K, 2% used [0x0000000647800000,0x000000064edd72f0,0x0000000742800000)
 Metaspace       used 71725K, capacity 76019K, committed 76248K, reserved 1114112K
  class space    used 9925K, capacity 10922K, committed 10968K, reserved 1048576K
```

So, what does `PSYoungGen: 267611K->5387K(255488K)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the size of the young gen was reduced from 267m to 5m, saving you 255m of RAM space.

See [this link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/useful-jvm-flags-part-8-gc-logging/) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. I will update the post.